# Loading an image from URL in a class

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying to load images from a URL on Swift, and instantiate it. I can compile my code, but it breaks when I compile the code.

this is my class code:

```
class Beer {
    let name : String
    let beernameInDB : String
    let imgUrl : NSURL
    var err : NSError?
    let imageData : NSData
    let img : UIImage
    init(name : String, imgUrl: String, beernameInDB : String){
        self.name = name
        self.imgUrl = NSURL.URLWithString(imgUrl);
        self.beernameInDB = beernameInDB
        self.imageData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(self.imgUrl,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)

        self.img = UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
}
```

And here is where I instantiate, and it breaks:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var array = [
        Beer(name: "Budweiser", imgUrl: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/1P45iR/upl[ad_upBR4q-large.png", beernameInDB:"Anheuser-Busch InBev-Budweiser")
     ]
```

When i run it, it breaks on this line of the class:

```
self.imageData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(self.imgUrl,options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: &err)
```

With the message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Essentially, I think its probably trying to assign a value to imageData before imgUrl is defined, so I tried changed that line to have 'NSURL.URLWithString(imgUrl)' instead of 'self.imgUrl', but it didn't fix, so I don't really know what is the problem right now

Answer (score 1):

This is a different technique but here is some simple code to load a web photo:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var containerView : UIView?
    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url = NSURL(string:"http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=AAPL&t=6m&q=l&l=on&z=s&p=m50,m200")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: apologies, down voted accidentally! Had to edit to be able to reverse